# Delete Dynamo DB items in the Dynamo DB table using Sort Keys

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I have the table in Dynamo DB called **test-items**
where `personKey` is the partitionKey and `date` is the sortkey

```
personKey | date       | accountNumber|
123       | 20220212   | A1           |
456       | 20220212   | A1           |
789       | 20220212   | A1           |
789       | 20220214   | A1           |
567       | 20220214   | A1           |
```

I have million such rows and the personKey is unpredictable , I want to delete all the items in the Dynamo DB Table deleted whose date is 20220212

```
aws dynamodb delete-item \
    --table-name "test-items" \
    --key '{"date": {"S": "20220212"}}'
```

This is not deleting the items for me

Answer (score 3):

You cannot delete items in DynamoDB without providing the primary key (partition + sort).

You would have to do the following:

1. Create a GSI with the partition key `date` (call it `date-index`):

```
aws dynamodb update-table \
    --table-name test-items \
    --attribute-definitions AttributeName=date,AttributeType=S  \
    --global-secondary-index-updates \
        "[
            {
                \"Create\": {
                    \"IndexName\": \"date-index\",
                    \"KeySchema\": [{\"AttributeName\":\"date\",\"KeyType\":\"HASH\"}],
                    \"Projection\":{
                        \"ProjectionType\":\"KEYS_ONLY\"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]"
```

2. [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html) the table for the items you want to remove

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name test-items \
    --index-name date-index \
    --key-condition-expression "#d = :badday" \
    --expression-attribute-names '{"#d": "date"}' \
    --expression-attribute-values  '{":badday":{"S":"20220212"}}'
```

You will get a list of items:

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "date": {
                "S": "20220212"
            },
            "personKey": {
                "S": "456"
            }
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "S": "20220212"
            },
            "personKey": {
                "S": "123"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Count": 2,
    "ScannedCount": 2,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

3. Record the primary keys of the offending records.
4. Delete them one-by-one:

```
aws dynamodb delete-item \
    --table-name test-items \
    --key '{"personKey": {"S": "456"}, "date": {"S": "20220212"}}'
```

Note that a more cost-effective way to remove a large number of items from the table may be to copy the items you want to keep into a new table and then delete the old table.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question depends a bit on how much data is in the table and how often you’ll be doing this. If it’s going to be a regular part of your process then the answer that @alex-chadyuk gave is what you want. If this is a one time operation then I’d just use a Scan rather than a query and not add a GSI. If the dataset is small the scan isn’t a terrible option either. You just have to weigh the cost and performance benefits of each.

Bottom line is that you need the full key, both partition and sort, to perform a delete. How you get that key is up to you, and should be based on your specific use case.